# How to get list of values from stored procedure using Linq?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I would like to get list of values from stored procedure. How to do it ?

```
create PROCEDURE Get_ListOf_Holiday
AS
BEGIN
    select * from holiday
END
```

In my Linq :

```
using (PlanGenEntities3 entity2 = new PlanGenEntities3())
{
   var testList = entity2.Get_ListOf_Holiday();
}
```

But I am always getting values like -1. But in my SQL server I am getting the output like list of holiday details.

How to solve this?

Comment: have you mapped your procedure properly...also instead of * replace it with the name of columns...Are you using entity framework ?

Comment: Is entity2 defined? Is this an entity to your database where the procedure lies?

Comment: Yes i am using Entity Framework to call stored procedure and get values using linq

Comment: I am also tried to replaced it instead of * to column name but getting same issues.

Comment: Please post the c# code which calls the stored procedure ie. the `Get_ListOf_Holiday()` definition

Comment: Have u dragged and drop your table Holiday on Linq-to-SQL frame work??

Answer (score 0):

First Drag and Drop your Holiday Table then drag and drop your procedure

When you drag and drop Procedure in LinQ-to-SQL then default return type is always 
auto generated type.

For Proper return type u need to rightclick procedure Name and click properties
change the return type equal to class name of Holiday Table.

That much details might help you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please help me to understand the question.
->Is PlanGenEntities3 a class name? If yes, then please change it because it does not convey its meaning, it should be singular, it should not contain a number  [in this case 3]
-> where have u used linq?
-> why do u want to access stored proc and not the table?.. You can get all the values of from 'holiday'..

You can use something like : var x = context.holiday.ToList();`

## Possible solution:-

if you are using Entity framework,you need to use a class inherited from System.Data.Entity.DbContext and use a context variable.

Now using this context variable to access data tables.

P.S: I am also new to programming,hope i can help if you share more details

Comment: ok, why do u want to access stored proc? u can select all the values from the table itself.. and are using a context variable?

Answer (score 0):

Use Dataset as return Type

```
  string dbConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DbName"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Proc Name", sqlConnection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Id
        command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nameValue;

        sqlConnection.Open();
        command.CommandTimeout = 30;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataSet result = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(result);
        sqlConnection.Close();
        return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using(PlanGenEntities3 db = new PlanGenEntities3()){
     IList<Entity> list = new List<Entity>();
     var query = db.Get_ListOf_Holiday();
     foreach (var m in query)
     {
       list.Add(new Entity()
       {
         Id = m.Id,
         Name = m.Name             
       });
      }
      return list;
}
```